# How do I highlight active code in a shiny app?

Tags: css, r, shiny, rstudio

IS there a way to highlight shiny app coding when the code is changed?

For example, the "Hello Shiny" example app:

```
library(shiny)
runExample("01_hello")
```

creates an app that includes the app code. This code is highlighted every time an action is executed (highlighting the code that is impacted).

[image]

**How do I do this with my own app??**

Comment: Your image doesn't work. Please fix it.

Comment: @Nikos it's working fine on my end, so I'm not sure what needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

```
shiny::runApp(display.mode="showcase")
```

You can get more information about this [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/debugging.html). See `Showcase Mode`

If you're using `shinyApp()` directly, try this:

```
shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(display.mode='showcase'))
```

Comment: perfect! Thanks!!