# How to make showcase mode work in rmarkdown/knitr interactive Shiny document?

Tags: r, shiny, markdown, rstudio, knitr

I learned from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43502074/4581200) that you can set shinyApp options to [`showcase mode`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/debugging.html) in order to visualize (i.e., highlight) which parts of your Shiny code are executing as a user interacts with your application.

However, when I try to apply this to an interactive Shiny doc using knitr/R markdown, the showcased code fails to show up.

**How can I make `showcase mode` work in an interactive doc?**

**Example:**

````
---
title: "Showcase Mode Doesn't Work in knitr"
output:  html_document
runtime: shiny
---

See, look, no highlatable code shows up with the app:

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput(inputId = 'textin', label = ''),
  textOutput(outputId = 'textout')
)
server <- function(input, output){
  output$textout <- renderText({input$textin})
  }
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(display.mode='showcase'))
```
````

Comment: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html

Comment: Hi @Petr. Which part of that document answers my question?

Comment: @Petr I know how to embed apps in rmarkdwon. My example app does that just fine. However, I cannot get the showcased code to show up in the document. That issue does not seem to be addressed at all in your link. Thanks.

Comment: I see it now, sorry, I misunderstood it. You have to use `shiny::runApp(display.mode="showcase")` to visualize it. Not in markdown, as answered by gscott.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you can't specify the `showcase mode` for a `markdown` document is simple - it doesn't exist.

`Knitr` (and `Rmarkdown` documents) is pre-rendering the output outcomes in an `html` page. In the case of the interactive `html` documents, it pre-renders all of the outputs for your "rendered object" and switches between them as specified by the input (if I understood the explanation given by Yihui Xie at Rconf this year).

Whereas in `shiny`, the output is generated dynamically because there is a backend (your computer, the server etc.) which is running the code new when the inputs are changed. That's why you can turn on `showcase` and see those things changing and being re-run dynamically.