# How to extend time of active code highlight in a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a Shiny project where the Shiny app contains large amount of code. I want to debug the app's code interactively using:

```
runApp("ShinyApp.R", launch.browser = TRUE, display.mode = "showcase")
```

The `display.mode = "showcase"` argument displays the active code next to the app in my browser and highlights the area where the user interacted with the app. Here is a good example of how this works: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/action-buttons.html

Another example of how it can be used is mentioned in this answer: [How do I highlight active code in a shiny app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43502074/how-do-i-highlight-active-code-in-a-shiny-app/43502314)

What I found challenging is that because my app's script contains over 800 lines of code, I am not able to see the highlighting when it occurs (it disappears too fast). As mentioned here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/display-modes.html, the highlighting disappears after a few moments.

**My questions are:**

Is it possible to increase the time until the highlighted area disappears?

Is there a way to force the side bar to scroll to the area where the highlighting occurs?

*Thank you for any suggestions or answers!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and yes, but you have to edit the source code and it's Javascript. The code in need of modification lives in `inst/www/shared/shiny-showcase.js`. I already made the code changes on [my fork of Shiny](https://github.com/nathancday/shiny/tree/showcase_scroll) if you want to start there.

For your first question about highlight duration, this is handled by the `JQuery` [highlight effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/highlight-effect/) on line 112:

```
// End any previous highlight before starting this one
jQuery(el)
  .stop(true, true)
  .effect("highlight", null, 5000);
```

The original is 1600, or 1.6 seconds, so I upped it here to 5 seconds. You can change it to whatever you think is best.

Your second question about scrolling to the active/highlighted code, isn't included in the original script but the ability to do is baked into web elements and called [`element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView). I just inserted this bit of code immediately after the highlighting block:

```
// Scroll to highlighted element
el.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
```

`el` is variable name currently pointing to the active code region to highlight.

Here is [hosted working demo](https://nathanday.shinyapps.io/demo/) of the tweaks in action.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have modified the relevant source code lines in my package library and it works - I've accepted your answer. Note: If anyone needs to find where is their shiny package located, just run `.libPaths()` in R Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer :) helped me a lot today!